# Why CSS padding not woking uniformly when applied to a div as a parent of an HTML form?

Tags: html, css

I have applied padding for only top and bottom of a div. The padding attribute is working homogeneously for the form element,but not for the div which is parent to the form as shown in the image below.

Output:-

[image]

```css
#content {
  font-family: arial;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #99ccff;
  padding: 10px 0px
}

#content form {
  background: #990000;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form>
    <label for="mid">MID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mid" id="mid" class="input" />
    <input type="submit" name="sbmit" id="sbmit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Firefox,Opera and Chrome all showing the same result.

I want to know why padding for the **div** is not showing homogeneous behaviour with respect to top and bottom layout with this regard?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: The divs seems to be padded 10px top and 10px bottom and 0px on the sides, just as your code is intending. What exactly is not working?

Comment: You should put your question back the way it was, it needs to be placed in a blank HTML file to show the behavior in question - doing it this way doesn't show the issue.

Comment: @rosemary no one has actually explained why your margin causes this so have a read of this: [Mastering collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Comment: @Pete Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put that CSS and HTML into a blank HTML file, the default user agent stylesheet is causing that problem - it gives the `<form>` element a default bottom margin of 1em that you need to override with `form { margin: 0; }`

Comment: form defaults is only margin-top:0em; where do you see that 1em for margin bottom?

Comment: @Salketer Create a blank html file. Place that code into it. Open in chrome. Inspect.

Comment: @jmcgriz I'm in agreement with Salketer.  I can't reproduce this even if I create a blank HTML file and open it with my browsers.  It's got to be a specific browser/OS combo that's doing this.  To whomever can reproduce this, what browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I have external CSS file for it. Putting: form { margin: 0; } really works. @jmcgriz

Comment: @rosemary Where is the style coming from?  Can you post a screenshot of the styles in developer tools?

Comment: when opening the HTML file from filesystem (not local webserver) I see the same thing as @jmcgriz, the user agent stylesheet put `margin-bottom: 1em` (Chrome 67)

Comment: @JosephMarikle It is in my local machine with PHP MySQL. I am testing it in localhost only.

Comment: @JosephMarikle It's happening in Chome 67 on OSX 10.12.6

Comment: @JosephMarikle I am using chrome/opera/firefox/windows xp

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<div class="content">` instead. The id only gives the div and ID and does not assign the css class.

Comment: You have to wrap it in back ticks: `

Comment: I don't want to downvote for your effort, but this is wrong, `#content` selector refers to the element with id "content"

Answer (score -2):

Simply add a comma to the `#content, form` ¿Is this what you were looking for?

```css
#content {
  font-family: arial;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #99ccff;
  padding: 10px 0px
}

#content, form {
  background: #990000;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form>
    <label for="mid">MID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="mid" id="mid" class="input" />
    <input type="submit" name="sbmit" id="sbmit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: adding a comma will apply the rule to two selectors instead of one. His problem is best described in his picture

Comment: Looks that i'm not understanding what he is trying to accomplish